# TYPO3 9.5 slug redirect for extbase records results in PageNotFoundException

Tags: redirect, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I want to be able to call blogpost entries by their slug, which is made of their title, through a `routeEnhancer`. The slug is generated correctly, but calling the URL results in a `PageNotFoundException` with the error message:

**Request parameters could not be validated (&cHash empty)**

And with links generated with Fluid:

```html
<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{'blogpost': blogpost}" pageUid="{settings.ShowPid}">Weiterlesen</f:link.action>
```

... I get **The requested page does not exist**

Using TYPO3 9.5.16

Here's my config:

`setup.typoscript`

```
plugin.tx_exblog {
    config {
        defaultGetVars = 0
    }
    features {
        requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 0
    }
}
```

`site/config.yaml`

```yaml
routeEnhancers:
    NewsPlugin:
        type: Extbase
        extension: ExBlog
        plugin: Show
        routes:
          - { routePath: '/{title}', _controller: 'Blogpost::show', _arguments: { title: blogpost } }
        defaultController: 'Blogpost::teaser'
        aspects:
          title:
            type: PersistedAliasMapper
            tableName: 'tx_exblog_domain_model_blogpost'
            routeFieldName: 'slug'
            routeValuePrefix: '/'
```

`TCA`

```php
'slug' => [
            'label' => 'slug',
            'exclude' => true,
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'slug',
                'generatorOptions' => [
                    'fields' => ['title'],
                    'fieldSeparator' => '/',
                    'prefixParentPageSlug' => true,
                    'replacements' => [
                        '/' => '',
                    ],
                ],
                'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
                'eval' => 'uniqueInSite',
            ],
        ]
```

`ext_tables.sql`

```sql
slug varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
```

Any ideas as to what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a change in TYPO3 v9.5.16 regarding `eval => "uniqueInSite"`. Please verify if you really want to keep the blogposts unique in site. If this is the case the "pid" of the blogposts need to be within the same site. If you don't need this, just switch the `eval` to `unique`

Comment: It worked in combination with setting the `routeValuePrefix` to `''` (empty). Thanks!