# TYPO3 - tx_news Speaking URL route if storage out of root page lead to error "The requested page does not exist"

Tags: typo3-9.x, tx-news

There are existing websites with page tree

Root Website 1

- Folder: News Storage 1
- Page: News List/Detail 1

Root Website 2

- Folder: News Storage 2
- Page: News List/Detail 2

When I try to show on "News List/Detail 2" Entity form "News Storage 1" its work for the list view. But in detail view, I have Error "`The requested page does not exist`" And the opposite.

If place Storage folder in the same level root page - don't work.
Also, if delete `routeEnhancers` From Site configuration - all works. It's simple:

```
  News:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{news-title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news-title: news

    defaultController: 'News::list'
    aspects:
      news-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
```

Looks like a problem with URL route. But how fix?

I use TYPO3 9.5.22, tx_news 7.3.1.

Question. How allow show entity in detail view from other root pages and use URL routing? Thx for the advice :)

Update: Same problem for another routing like Extbase. If skip SLUG from routing configuration all works). Like, use title instead of the slug. Should be a problem in slug prefix or suffix logic.

So config like that

```
News:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{news-title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news-title: news

    defaultController: 'News::list'
    aspects:
      news-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: uid
```

Works but URLs are not the best looking (. Why slug is buggy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in other case here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673990/4796923. I pretty sure that this case will appear for other developers.

The problem in slug configuration:

Original configuration

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['columns']['path_segment']['config'] = [
    'type' => 'slug',
    'size' => 50,
    'generatorOptions' => [
        'fields' => ['title'],
        'replacements' => [
            '/' => '-'
        ],
    ],
    'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
    'eval' => 'uniqueInSite',
    'default' => ''
];
```

option `eval' => 'uniqueInSite'` don't work if you need use Entitties over cross website, so you need replace to `eval' => 'unique'`

And all works. Im my case also was needed add `routeValuePrefix: ''` in routing config like

```
aspects:
  fund_slug:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: tx_lloyd_domain_model_fund
    routeFieldName: slug
    routeValuePrefix: ''
```

But for tx_news firs fix works

Comment: Thank you for this solution. eval' => 'unique' helped me a lot!